# How to generate a list of first day of each month between the two dates in power query

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

in power query I'm trying to generate list of rows depending on the existing columns StartOfDate and EndOfDate.
I want to add a New Column which has a list of dates like below table.

| StartOfDate | EndOfDate | New Column |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023/1/1 | 2023/2/15 | List |
| 2023/2/3 | 2023/4/2 | List |

After expanding the list, I only need the first day of months between the StartOfDate and EndOfDate.

| StartOfDate | EndOfDate | New Column |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023/1/1 | 2023/2/15 | 2023/1/1 |
| 2023/1/1 | 2023/2/15 | 2023/2/1 |
| 2023/2/15 | 2023/4/2 | 2023/2/1 |
| 2023/2/15 | 2023/4/2 | 2023/3/1 |
| 2023/2/15 | 2023/4/2 | 2023/4/1 |

I know I can just generate a list by {Number.From([StartOfDate])..Number.From([EndOfDate])} and then get all the dates between the two date by expanding the list.

But I only need the first day of each month between the dates...

And, since there are already many rows in the table, I do not want to create a step in the query to expand lists of all the dates.

Does anyone know how to to this?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add column, custom column,

```
 =List.Distinct(List.Transform({Number.From([StartOfDate])..Number.From([EndOfDate])}, each Date.StartOfMonth(Date.From(_))))
```

then expand the column into rows using the arrows atop the new column

Answer (score 3):

Just for fun, an alternative using `List.Generate()`:

```
=let s=Date.StartOfMonth([StartOfDate]), e=[EndOfDate] in List.Generate(()=>s, each _<=e, each Date.AddMonths(_,1))
```